# Input Labels Fixed Width

Tags: html, css, input

I would like the labels for the inputs to be the same width allowing the inputs and labels to be like a table.

Kind of like two columns: 1 for the labels and 1 for the inputs

Code So Far:

```css
th, td, table{border: 2px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td{width: 100px}

table{width: 100%;
text-align: center;}

body{font-family: "Bradley's Hand", cursive;}

.label{display: inline-block;
width: 100px}

input{width: 200px;}
```

```html
<body>
<h1>Add Transactions</h1>

<fieldset>
<legend>Use This Form To Add Transactions</legend>

<form action="add.php" method="post">
<label class="label" for="date">Transaction Date: </label>

<input type="date" name="date" required>
<br>
<br>
<label class="label" for="amount">Transaction Amount: </label>
<input type="number" name="amount" required>
<br>
<br>
<label class="label" for="merchant">Merchant: </label>
<select name="merchant" required>
<option value="" disable selected>Select One</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<label class="label" for="om">Other Merchant: </label>
<input type="text" name="om">
<br><br>
<label for="type" class="label">Transaction Type: </label>
<select name="type" required>
<option value="" disable selected>Select One</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<label for="ot" class="label">Other Transaction Type: </label>
<input type="text" name="ot">
<br><br>
<label for="source" class="label">Source: </label>
<select name="source" required>
<option value="" disable selected>Select One</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<label for="os" class="label">Other Source: </label>
<input type="text" name="os">
<br>
<br>
<input type="reset">
<input type="submit" value="Save Transaction">
</form>
</fieldset>
</body>
</htm>
```

Thanks!

P.S. I can give more details if I am not clear enough!

P.P.S. What I mean by

> like a table

is like the structure. Not like an actual table with `<table>`

Comment: How about CSS flex or grid?

Comment: Also, maybe provide some context on why you don't want to use a table and what the requirements are. Otherwise nobody can be sure that they'll offer you a good solution.

Comment: @Kielstra because using table as a layout tool is a wrong use. Since CSS3 you have a full browser support for CSS-Grid (with exeption of IE) and Flex-boxes which can do the same thing much cleaner and with way less HTML coding. It can be purely styled with CSS which also alows to rearrange for full responsivness in combination with media queries. For example switching a multiple column layout to a hamburger layout in mobile use.

Comment: @tacoshy Those are very good reasons. I didn't think about it that way yet.

Comment: One thing to add: SO is not a forum where you ask to close a question. A question will only be closed if it does not meet the SO guidelines and is either voted to be closed or someone with a specific SO badge. Questions that meet the SO guidelines will stay open for other users to use aswell.

Comment: @tacoshy Well I didn't want to delete the question but didn't want it be active so people know that I don't need more help!

Comment: you have done that by marking an anwser ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to solve it: CSS-Grid. Will allow for full responsiveness and create a table like layout. to leave the buttons at the bottom as they where, I wrapped them inside an extra div.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Bradley's Hand", cursive;
}

form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  grid-row-gap: 2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.last-row {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.last-row input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Add Transactions</h1>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Use This Form To Add Transactions</legend>

    <form action="add.php" method="post">
      <label class="label" for="date">
        Transaction Date:
      </label>
      <input type="date" name="date" required>

      <label class="label" for="amount">
        Transaction Amount:
      </label>
      <input type="number" name="amount" required>

      <label class="label" for="merchant">
        Merchant:
      </label>
      <select name="merchant" required>
        <option value="" disable selected>
          Select One
        </option>
        <option value="other">
          Other
        </option>
      </select>
      
      <label class="label" for="om">
        Other Merchant:
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="om">

      <label for="type" class="label">
        Transaction Type:
      </label>
      <select name="type" required>
        <option value="" disable selected>
          Select One
        </option>
        <option value="other">
          Other
        </option>
      </select>

      <label for="ot" class="label">
        Other Transaction Type:
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="ot">

      <label for="source" class="label">Source: </label>
      <select name="source" required>
        <option value="" disable selected>
          Select One
        </option>
        <option value="other">
          Other
        </option>
      </select>

      <label for="os" class="label">Other Source: </label>
      <input type="text" name="os">
      <div class="last-row">
        <input type="reset">
        <input type="submit" value="Save Transaction">
      </div>
    </form>
  </fieldset>
</body>
</htm>
```

Comment: Thanks  So Much! That Worked! Do we need the inputs to be super long? I will figure it out!

Comment: no of course not. you can delcare the width as much as long as youw ant with `grid-template-columns: column-1 column-2;` currently the first column is set to `min-content` which will use up only as much space as needed and the 2nd column to `auto` which will fill up all remaining space of the parent.

Comment: Thanks! So Much!